# How do I repeat the last external command

Tags: vim

I would like to have the following behavior for a key in `vim` (for example the F8 key):

*Find the most recent ex command starting with `:!` and repeat it.*

For example, if my command history is

```
(...)
:!python abc.py
/hi
:%s/hi/ho/g
:w
```

then by pressing F8 I would like vim to run `:!python abc.py`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`:!!` repeats the last `:!{cmd}`. You can map it to F8 like so:

```
:nnoremap <F8> :!!<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nnoremap <F8> :!<UP><ENTER>
```

Comment: You always want to use non-recursive mappings (eg. `nnoremap`, and not `nmap`). [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way has a good explanation on why](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <F8> q:?^!<CR><CR>
```

Explanation:

- `q:` - open the command-line window
- `?^!` - search for a line starting with `!`
- `<CR><CR>` - hit enter twice to execute that command